# OpenLayers time to layer (time control)

Tags: javascript, time, openlayers, tile

I am new to OpenLayers and I would like to have something takes (date+time) and to get (layer) on the map

E.g I have layers for the Weather in (15.02.2010), (16.02.2010) and so on.

for example.. user enter (date+time) and the result (layer of the same date on the map)

Are there any ideas? Example? API!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does date + time have to do with map tiles? Maybe a translation error?

Comment: e.g (I have tiles about weather details in 2015 in png format), so user enter (2015), he gets the weather tiles over the map).. so I need a function to call this layer from a certain date & time.

Comment: So with tiles you mean you have a service that delivers x,y,z tiles and you want do display a _layer_ over your base map?

Comment: yeah exactly, I did the projection, I implement (ol.layer.Tile) but still need some function to take time as input and the result is a tile.. I didn't find something similar in oL API

Comment: well entering the data and sending it to openlayers is not OL's task, it just displays data. You have to build some kind of html form and when the users hits the "show it" button, modify the layer's source (or remove the layer and add it again with the new options)

Comment: Actually, there is even an example for it: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reusable-source.html?q=xyz

Comment: So If I implement a time box (contains labels for date and time and button to start show), how can I connect it to my tile ? to show it.. thanks in advance

Comment: I will try this example to do something similar, hope it gonna works... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the [OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reusable-source.html?q=xyz):

```
<input type="text" name="customParam" id="customParam">
<button onclick="showIt()">show it</button>

<script>
  let source = null;

  const map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
  });

  function showIt() {
    const customParam = document.getElementById("customParam").value;
    const isNew = (!source);

    if(isNew) {
      source = new ol.source.XYZ();
    }

    source.setUrl(`https://{a-c}.MY-TILES.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?myTimeParam=${customParam}`);
    source.refresh();

    if(isNew) {
      map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({ source: source }));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How can I work (add the layers) on my defined old ol.map not the new one..

Comment: what do you mean "not the new one?" `map.addLayer(layerObject)` adds layers, `map.removeLayer(layerObject)` removes it

Comment: I already define on my code as follows....................................................... var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                logo:false,
                view: new ol.View({
                    projection: 'EPSG:40118',
                    center: [90, 0],
                }),

Comment: look at the example above and at the comment: `map.addLayer(layerObject)`

Comment: Please use the stackoverflow chat for subsequential questions

Comment: Oh Sorry, I am new here so I didn't know. also I don't have enough reputations

Comment: Oh wow, i didnt know. Then I guess just open new question for those questions. PS: dont set the projection on the view bit on your source, that way each source can have its own projection. You can use multiple layers and show/hide them wit setVisible